# Is there an onomatopoeia of mumbling in japanese?

Tags: onomatopoeia

I was watching an anime, and they use repetitions of "ブツ" everytime a character is mumbling. Is this the rule for japanese or it's just something made up for a particular anime/manga?

Comment: Cross-posted on Anime.SE: [Is it usual in anime/manga/japanese to use ブツ as onomatopoeia of mumbling?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/47387)

Comment: In my experience, the question to "is there an onomatopoeia of X in japanese?" is always "yes", no matter what X is.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For mumbling, there are 「ブツブツ」、「ボソボソ」、「ブツクサ」, etc.  Those three are commonly used.

If you did not know, we have an onomatopoeia for "everything" including things that do not even make any actual sound.

Comment: That's interesting, can you give me an example of an onomatopoeia for something that doesnt make a sound?

Comment: シーン is an onomatopoeia for silence!

Comment: or ジー which is is for staring.

Comment: Chinese sometimes does the same, like [咿唔](https://baike.baidu.com/item/咿唔), which is ‘the sound of reading’.

Answer (score 3):

Besides ブツブツ, another onomatopoeia of mumbling in Japanese is ゴニョゴニョ
([reference](https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%94%E3%81%AB%E3%82%87%E3%81%94%E3%81%AB%E3%82%87)).

Example in the [wild](https://www.kango-roo.com/ca/topics/8504/):

> ゴニョゴニョ何言ってるのか分からない

Another [one](https://ameblo.jp/kotori-hoshi/entry-12348886198.html):

> 高音のロボットが何やらゴニョゴニョ言ってる（このゴニョゴニョの中身は分からない）

Beware that it can also have other meanings, though, or can have a nuance of "blablabla".